# Axis2 and Spring3 integration

Tags: apache-axis, spring-3

I have an Web application developed using Spring3. Some functions of Web app needs to be exposed as Web services also. 
Web app is deployed in the Tomcat Server as a .war file. 
I have gone through Axis2 and Spring integration in the site http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/spring.html. What I am unclear is how the final structure looks like. Need clarifiaction on the below points,

1) What should be the directory structure of my final app for "With ServletContext" as well as "Without ServletContext" ?

2)The .aar file also should be placed in WEB-INF/lib directory? If so how does axis2 recognize this as service as it has compulsion on the directory structure like .aar file and inside it META-INF which contains services.xml. and the classes at the same level as META-INF folder.

I am not sure if I am going wrong in getting the whole picture. Any guidelines or a good tutorial would be highly helpful.